# Switching Applications server on different VM snapshot

Tags: vmware-esxi, snapshot, application-server

I have a VMware VM running with a specific Application Server.

Instead of creating a new VM for install a new application server, Is it a good practice creating a snapshot of old Application Server VM and then go to clean_instalation snapshot and install the new Application Server?

Does exit any problem switching Sotware on servers through VM Machines Snapshots?

EDIT:
**I have no rights to create a new VM**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest relying on snapshots for this purpose.

Depending on the version of VMware you have installed, you can *clone* an existing virtual machine or leverage the template functions of vCenter. Outside of that, I would just reinstall onto a new virtual machine if you have the access.

If you don't have access to do this, check with the person/group responsible for the infrastructure.

Comment: It is just for testing... I am not system administrator then I cannot clone machines etc. I will create a snapshot. If I get some problems I will post them hire.

Comment: DO NOT leave snapshots in place for more than a few days, they're not designed for this role. If you can't use the correct tools as ewwhite suggests then either request those tools or do it a different way.

Comment: @Chopper3. thats what VMWARE says: A snapshot preserves the state and **data** of a virtual machine at a specific point in time. thats what all what I need.

Comment: @kmxillo They also say a lot of other things:

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1025279

Comment: Snapshots are complex, and you'd do well to spend some time learning about them before arguing with people

Comment: If you're not the sysadmin, please try working *with them*, to achieve your needs.

Comment: @kmxillo - I know fully well what they say, I'm well qualified in their products, speak on VMWare podcasts and have some PR work for them - and one of the first things they say when you go on even the most basic of their courses is that you shouldn't leave snapshots around for long as they're designed for short-term usage, anything more and you WILL cause yourself, and others, problems. Look on this site, we get regular "snaps have screwed me over because I left them around too long" questions, I wasn't in the mood to waste my time when I commented.

Comment: @Chopper3 thanks for your extend explanation. as you can observed I am not an expert as you.... thanks to pages like this, inexpert users are learning little by little.